# Why do I see output if buffer is not full and program is not terminated?

Tags: c++, buffer, flush

As much as I know, we do not get output to the screen from cout, until:

1.Buffer is full

2.Buffer is flushed

3.Program is terminated

So i have written following Code:

```
for(;;)
{
cout << "a";
_sleep(1000);
}
```

Compiler:clang++

Also tested on g++

OS: Windows 11

Every second I get an output? Why and how?

Comment: Maybe the buffer has size 1. Actually I believe the 3 points are the times you are guaranteed to see output, but nothing states that you won't see output before that.

Comment: Cannot reproduce on Windows (atm no linux available to test there as well) – using `std::this_thread::sleep_for` or windows `Sleep` both result in the behaviour you expect. Might be OS or compiler specific, you should add this information.